# Get users that a given user is FOLLOWING (not followers) in LinqToTwitter

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

How can I get UserId and ScreenName of the users that a given user is FOLLOWING (not followers) in LinqToTwitter?

```
??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API uses the terms *follower* to mean people who follow a user and *friends* to mean people that a user follows and LINQ to Twitter continues that approach. So, you would use a `Friendship`/`FriendshipType.FriendsList` query, like this:

```
    static async Task FriendsListAsync(TwitterContext twitterCtx)
    {
        Friendship friendship;
        long cursor = -1;
        do
        {
            friendship =
                await
                (from friend in twitterCtx.Friendship
                 where friend.Type == FriendshipType.FriendsList &&
                       friend.ScreenName == "JoeMayo" &&
                       friend.Cursor == cursor &&
                       friend.Count == 200
                 select friend)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            if (friendship != null && 
                friendship.Users != null && 
                friendship.CursorMovement != null)
            {
                cursor = friendship.CursorMovement.Next;

                friendship.Users.ForEach(friend =>
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "ID: {0} Name: {1}",
                        friend.UserIDResponse, friend.ScreenNameResponse)); 
            }

        } while (cursor != 0);
    }
```

This example pages through the results in a `do`/`while` loop. Notice that the `cursor` is set to `-1`, which starts off the query without a Twitter API cursor. Each query assigns the `cursor`, which gets the next page of users. In the `if` block, the first statement reads the `friendship.CursorMovement.Next` to the get `cursor` for the next page of users. When the next `cursor` is `0`, you've read all of the followers.

After the query executes, the `Users` property has a `List<User>` where you can get user information. This demo prints each member of the list.

One of the things you might run into with large friend lists is that Twitter will return an error for exceeding the rate limit. You'll be able to catch this, in a `try`/`catch` block, by catching `TwitterQueryException` and examining properties for the Rate Limit Exceeded. To minimize rate limit propblems, set `count` to `200`, the max. Otherwise count defaults to 20.

You can download [samples](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/blob/master/Samples/net46/CSharp/ConsoleSamples/FriendshipDemos.cs) and view [documentation](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Showing-Friends) for this on the LINQ to Twitter Web site.

Comment: I appreciate very much your prompt response. I did not have much time to go over LINQ to Twitter to figure this out, but there is no doubt it is very useful well done product. I want to thank you for your efforts on building it, on behalf of all developers.

Comment: Cannot edit it but is missing "&&" after "friend.Cursor == cursor", Thanks.